# What's the best way in Java to implement a callable that takes a constant time to complete

Tags: java, brute-force, java.util.concurrent

To protect against password brute-forcing, and to protect against timing attacks trying to detect valid usernames, I want my login process to take a constant amount of time regardless of successful authentication or not. In short I always want my login process to take say 1000ms (assume either outcome takes fractions of that time), regardless of the outcome. What's the best way to accomplish this in Java? This is my current thinking:

```
class ConstantDuration<T> implements Callable<T> {

 ConstantDuration(Callable<T> task,long duration) {
  this.task = task;
  this.duration = duration;
 }

 public T call() throws Exception {
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long elapsed = 0;
  T result = null;
  try {
   result = task.call();
  } finally {
    elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
  }
  if ( elapsed < duration ) {
   Thread.sleep(duration-elapsed);
  }
  return result;
 }
}
```

Comment: The code itself looks pretty good. Will be a performance hit on your server though.

Comment: @duffymo, the if clause protects against a negative duration

Comment: Didn't look carefully enough.  I still don't see much point in it.

Comment: @Perception, can you expand on why it will be a performance hit? I'm aware I'm hogging a thread for the duration, can't see a way round that, is that what you meant?

Comment: @z0f0 - yes, the increase in number of hosted threads is the performance hit. If possible though, you could split authentication logic to a separate server from your application cluster, assuming you have that flexibility in your architecture.

Comment: @duffymo, the point is that making the login take a fairly long time throttles the brute forcer in how many attempts they can make. Making the time taken constant frustrates the brute forcer because they can't differentiate between a successful login and a failed login on timing signature alone. If success took 10ms and fail took 100ms or had a 1000ms delay to attempt throttling then an attacker can stop listening for any response after 10ms knowing they must be getting a fail, and immediately submit another attempt (from a different ip address if necessary)

Comment: @z0f0: If someone wants to remotely brute-force your server, she will do it in parallel anyways (and from different IP adresses if available), without waiting first if the answer will be yes or no. It will become a competition of resources between you and the attacker if you block one thread for every asking thread (and the attacker might not even block a thread for every call).

Comment: Isn't it more common to delay only on a failed attempt?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann good point, effectively, my approach could provide an accelerant for a DOS attack (all threads consumed, spinning their wheels to give a constant round trip), sigh :(

Comment: First, I wouldn't punish people who successfully authenticate by making them wait. You're going to give the impression that the site is slow. Second, it isn't good to keep threads stalled like that, I agree that its an easy DOS attack; if everything is asynchronous then you could scale that out more easily, but I don't think the DOS issue would go away entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you'll want to move sleeping into the finally block so it also occurs if task throws an Exception (for instance a PasswordExpiredException?).

The other problem is handling the case `elapsed > duration`. You say that never happens, but are you sure? What if your database query gets stalled by a lock? Assuming you want to deny authentication in such an event, you could do:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

<T> T doInConstantTime(Callable<T> task, long millis, T defaultResponse) {
    Future<T> future = exec.submit(task);
    Thread.sleep(millis);
    if (future.isDone()) {
        return future.get();
    } else {
        future.cancel(false); // or true? 
        return defaultResponse;
    }
}
```

(You'll need to add proper exception handling, of course)

I am not sure though this is a good way to defend against brute force attacks, though. Instead, we invalidate a user's login after the third consequtive failed login attempt (for a certain period of time or until an administrator unlocks the account). Mention somewhere that you do this, and nobody has a reason to brute force passwords.

Comment: Thanks, think this code is definitely preferable to mine and good spot with the finally block! Worth saying it's a defense in depth measure, captchas, ip-bans, account locking all in the mix as well

Comment: I did this too, but I just did by always checking the hashed password, even though the username is wrong, which takes most of the time of validating the credentials (~500ms). Response time variation by the database or server load are good, they make it harder for the attacker. @z0f0: account locking does not help, because attacker needs to know whether the login name is incorrect or the password.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to let each login try take some minimum time, and at the same time want to be able to handle larger amounts of users (like 1000 logins each second), there is no way of handling this with the simple "let the thread wait some time" model - you are DOS-ing yourself, basically, since in Java, each thread takes some resources, and thus the total number of threads is limited, even if they are not really doing anything.

To stay scalable, you should use asynchronous I/O to take the login requests from the users, check the password (maybe also asynchronously), set a timer for when to revisit this user's connection, and then reply (also asynchronously). Java makes this quite complicated to write (and then read), unfortunately.

Comment: agreed, and my hands are even more tied by the fact that the code lives in a servlet container, so doing async like you suggest isn't possible. My only get out of jail is that concurrent logins won't be huge, but regardless it can still act as a DOS attack point.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to cut the call to result = task.call(); if it exceeds 1000ms?
All you need is a function that does not return before t1 time whether the execution is done or not.
A simple solution would be,  using sleep or await in the executing thread after submitting the task to a thread pool executor. And then check if the future.isDone(). If not cancel if yes you have already waited for 1000ms.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is a static method, there is no point in using `Thread.currentThread().sleep()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping inside your thread will mean that the thread won't be able to do anything. That won't scale.

Use a scheduled executor and schedule a delayed task that would return the result in the future.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html